# How to run Promise test in Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, promise, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a promise in a separate library I injected to my app.

```js
function myFunc(input) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             ···
            resolve(value); // success
            ···
            reject(error); // failure
        });
    };
```

This is my function that returns a Promise.

I would seriously love to run the test in jasmine like this

```js
describe('Service: myService', function () {
    var $log;

beforeEach(inject(function (_$log_) {
    $log = _$log_;
}));

it('should get results', function () {
    $log.log("start test");

    var self = this;
    myFunc(input).then(function(response) {
            $log.log("success");
            expect(response).toBe("response");
            done();
    }).catch(function(error) {
            $log.log("fail");
            self.fail(error);
            done();
    });
    $log.log("end test");
});
});
```

My test passes(not expected.) and the only thing in my log is [start test] and [end test] as if the promise is totally ignored. 
Since I'm not using $q for the promise, most jasmine tips angular doesn't seem to be helpful.

Any ideas on how to get into that 'then'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but this is most likely because you are attempting to test an asynchronous process here. So essentially what is happening, is that you call the function, but the test continues running and finishes before the promise ever returns, which is why the test succeeds.

One way to work around this (this is more like a hack, I'm sure there is a better way to do this, and if I find it, I will edit this post) is to add this bit of code at the end of your test:

```
describe("baseline test",function(){
    it("baseline",function(done){
        setTimeout(function(){
            expect(1).toEqual(1);
            done();
        },1000);    
    });
});
```

Essentially what this snippet does is just set a timeout that waits for 1 second for any asynchronous calls to call back. If 1 second isn't enough, you can always increase that 1000 (which is in milliseconds). If this doesn't work, maybe look into adding another test suite that won't complete until the promises return.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but now am getting timeout error. I think the thread gets lost somehow. Still figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

**TypeScipt code (Angular 8) to be tested**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
import { LoggedInUserHelperService } from 'shared/helper/logged-in-user-helper.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppInitializationService {

  constructor(public keycloakService: KeycloakService) {
  }

  initApplication(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>(
        async (resolve: any, reject: any): Promise<any> => {
          await this.initKeycloak()
              .then(() => keyCloakInitialized = true)
              .catch((error: Error) => {
                console.error(`Couldn\'t initialize Keycloak Service. (Error: ${error})`);
                reject(error);
                return;
              });

          resolve();
        }
    );
  }

  private async initKeycloak(): Promise<any> {
    return this.keycloakService.init({
      config: environment.keycloak,
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        checkLoginIframe: false,
        promiseType: 'legacy'
      },
      enableBearerInterceptor: true,
      bearerExcludedUrls: ['/assets']
    });
  }
}
```

**Tests**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppInitializationService } from 'app/app-initialization.service';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

describe('AppInitializationService', () => {

  let testObj: AppInitializationService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        KeycloakService
      ]
    });
    testObj = TestBed.get(AppInitializationService);
  });

  it('should call keycloak service init', async () => {
    const spy = spyOn(testObj.keycloakService, 'init').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));

    await testObj.initApplication();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      config: environment.keycloak,
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        checkLoginIframe: false,
        promiseType: 'legacy'
      },
      enableBearerInterceptor: true,
      bearerExcludedUrls: ['/assets']
    });
  });


  it('should log error on failed keycloak initialization', async () => {
    const errorMsg = 'error-msg';
    const spy1 = spyOn(testObj.keycloakService, 'init').and.callFake(
        () => Promise.reject(errorMsg));
     const spy2 = spyOn(console, 'error');

    await testObj.initApplication().catch(() => { return; });

    expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(spy2).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(spy2).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`Couldn\'t initialize Keycloak Service. (Error: ${errorMsg})`);
  });
});
```